# I need the alert when color dialog was closed without any action

Tags: javascript

I am Trying to catch the event when the color dialog was closed without any action and get the alert then. I am using onfocus and onblur, because color dialog has no close event.

This demo has to paint the text which was inserted in the text input element.
It does its job, but if the color was not changed from the previous case or if the color dialog was closed without any action nothing happens.

And this is what I would like to upgrade to have an alert in this case.
I was trying 231 different options but I am giving up (check the fiddle update number ).
This is the demo code.  But my app works the same way. Actually getting the color from the color dialog is one step of one configuration process. That's why is important to notify the user that he has to choose some color other-ways configuration process will be aborted.
I hope to get a solution which I could then integrate into my app.
But let me resume it. If I change the color - all is fine. If I select the same color as I had in the previous case - all is fine also because I have some other task which I did not include in this demo to notify me about this.
But if I get to point when I open the color dialog and if I click on "OK", "Cancel" or "X", then I need the alert message.

If you go through the case and observe how values are acting in the console you could probably get an idea how to solve this. I hope.

```js
var someText;
function createStatusF(){ 
countClose=0;
 someText  = prompt("Enter some text :", ""); 

   if ((someText=="")||(someText==null)){       
      return;
   }


 document.getElementById("colorDialogID").focus();
  document.getElementById("colorDialogID").value = "#FFCC00";
  document.getElementById("colorDialogID").click();

 }

document.getElementById("newlabelID").onclick = createStatusF;
//document.getElementById("colorDialogID").style.display = "none";

function peintTheText(){
document.getElementById("aID").innerHTML= someText;
var theColor=document.getElementById("colorDialogID").value;
document.getElementById("aID").style.color=theColor;
console.log(theColor);
}
document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onchange=peintTheText;

var countClose=0;
var type1;

function onfocusF(){
type1 = $(colorDialogID).attr('type');
countClose=countClose+1;
console.log(countClose+type1);
}

document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onfocus=onfocusF;
function onblurF(){
type1 = $(colorDialogID).attr('type');
countClose=countClose+1;
console.log(countClose+type1);
}
document.getElementById("colorDialogID").onblur=onblurF;
```

```css
#colorDialogID {
     position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
     width: 0px;
     height: 0px;
     opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="newlabelID" value="Open input element to insert text  "/></br>
 <input type="color" id="colorDialogID" ></br>
 <a id="aID"> Text to paint</br>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pr2501/jvrk6qcw/231/

Comment: I only get `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Comment: @melpomene, yes, I just edited to add jquery to the snippet. Try again

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Why did you add that? It's not in OP's original code. The demo on jsfiddle throws the same error.

Comment: @melpomene, the fiddle does not throw that error.

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: Don't know why, but I added jquery because the OP is clearly using jquery and forgot to import it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not answer to your exact question, but you can try `hide` event of [this tutorial](https://www.lugolabs.com/articles/how-to-use-a-color-picker-in-javascript) because there is no `close` event for color dialog. [Here](https://github.com/lugolabs/tutorials/tree/master/colorpicker) is github repository of tutorial.